# How to implement BLE security?

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

We implemented the communication between a Linux device and mobile app via BLE. We are able to read and write data by using a free app "nRF Connect". 
Now we need to support the BLE security. Basically our data is sensitive. We want to protect our data from MITM. So we need to support a reasonable high standard of security. It seems "Security Mode 1, Level 3: Authenticated pairing with encryption" is what we need. Our device doesn't support visually input. We use BlueZ, D-Bus and Python3 on the Linux side.

But I have some practical questions:

1. For pairing, how do we support password protection? Is this something only for the mobile app developer?
2. How do we know when pairing happens on the Linux side? Is there a callback or notification we can use from BlueZ Python API?
3. How does data encryption work? Some mentioned AES-CMAC, some mentioned AES-CCM? Which one should we use? So we'll just need to encrypt the data on the Linux Python and send the data?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to initiate a pairing before connecting to LE device, you'll have to set le, secure-conn and bondable using [btmgmt tool](https://helpmanual.io/help/btmgmt/). Based on the LE version supported by your hardware, you can (in a way) do a passkey based pairing. With reference to [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116027/difference-between-secure-simple-pairing-and-secure-connections-in-bluetooth) and [this](https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/Wireless/A+Basic+Introduction+to+BLE+Security) link, if we give IO capability of your Linux device as DisplayYesNo (see [agent capabilities](https://www.kynetics.com/docs/2018/pairing_agents_bluez/#d-bus-api)), you could initiate a pair using passkey comparison if the hw support LE 4.2 or above. In any other case where LE version is below 4.2, you will require some way of keyboard input or display output to carry out passkey based pairing.(disclaimer: I have only tried with legacy pairing for LE,i.e., <4.2 and it does require some way of input or output for passkey based pairing. Findings on 4.2+ is based on the readings).
2. You will have to define a pairing agent and register it using the Blue Z agent Manager API. Whenever a pairing key request comes or a prompt for confirmation comes you'll get corresponding callbacks to the registered agent. You can define what should be done in the agent implementation. You can refer the agent API [here](https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blob/master/doc/agent-api.txt) and a sample implementation in bluez test code (test/simple-agent)
3. I think, bluez will take of the encryption when you set characteristic property as "encrypt-write" or "encrypt-read". I do not have much information on this area but you can refer [this](http://www.fte.com/WebHelp/BPA600/Content/Documentation/WhitePapers/BTLE/HowEncryptionWorksInBluetoothLowEnergy.htm) for how encryption works in LE and you can use some hci log capture tool to capture and analyze the hci data and see what is happening down the layers during pairing procedure ([example: btmon to capture hci logs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingBluetooth))